# Do Snails Need to be Acclimated to Aquarium?

Tags: aquarium, invertebrates

I recently purchased some Assassin snails. Do they need to be acclimated?  I acclimated shrimp and fish using the slow drip method in the past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snails are generally much more resistant to water changes than fish (and definitely shrimp).

So I would not bother to acclimate them, or definitely not for the same duration as with fish or shrimps. E.g. 15 minutes or so, just to be safe.

I bought a few a few of these a while back and just dropped them in my tank. I also transferred them from 1 tank to another, without any problems or deaths.

Comment: Same with me. I have also Assassin snails and they breed slowly but when I put them in other tanks I do not acclimante them either. They seem to be quite tough. Unfortunately I dropped one and found it only one day later. I could not believe it but it survived.

Comment: I agree that they don't really need a drip, but I have better results if I float the bag first.

Comment: I ended up just throwing them in and they did great.  They started moving around as soon as they hit the substrate and have already put a dent in the pond snail population.